# Is there a definitive Recluce timeline?

Tags: l-e-modesitt, saga-of-recluce

The Recluce novels span thousands of years of history, and their relative chronological order is easy to work out in most cases.  However, I haven't been able to find a good source that actually indicates the absolute timespans between novels.

I'm aware of [this link](http://www.travelinlibrarian.info/recluce/recluce/chronology.html) from the main fan site, which calls itself the "Official" timeline and is used as a source by Wikipedia, but it isn't actually accurate.  First of all, it starts in year 1, even though the chronologically-first novel takes place in a well-established empire.  Additionally, the next book being released is going to happen even earlier in that empire's history, thereby potentially pushing back "Year 1".  Finally, the novels themselves sometimes disagree with it - for example, *The White Order* says that the last few events of *Towers of the Sunset* happened 287 years previously, whereas the timeline places 190 years between them.

Is there either a [Word of God](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) source saying the timeline as posted is correct, or a separate, better-sourced timeline posted anywhere?

Comment: I think that site you linked is pretty close to word of god. According to the website they get their info directly from Modesitt: http://www.travelinlibrarian.info/recluce/credits.html 

And a guy claiming to be the author also posts in their forum: http://www.ibdof.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=445&sid=9e1203271fb5b821e88a8e4bd8ad7352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some time between August 31st and October 4th of 2023 (based on Internet Archive captures), Modesitt added a [definitive chronology](https://www.lemodesittjr.com/recluce-chronology/) to his official website. It mostly parallels the fan-generated list I linked to above, although it adds new books that have come out since then and starts the clock 400 years earlier, so most years are +400 from where they were.

That also addresses my biggest issue with the fan list, which was that it started in year 1. Now that novel is year 410, which makes much more sense.